# Android: How to check if an application has new inner notifications (ticker)?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I don't want to read status bar notifications, I already know how to do that using the following tutorial:

http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2015/05/android-read-status-bar-notification.html

Majority launchers shows a ticker (red circle or number) indicating that an application (As Facebook, Telephone, Messages, etc.) has un-previewed notifications, which is not available in Notifications Panel.

How to accomplish this? How to find that an application (Using it's package name / Activity Name) has an active inner notifications?

Comment: What do you mean by _active inner notifications_? Internal messages that are not push notifications, so they are not normally shown in the status bar?

Comment: @Adinia Let's take Facebook app as example, it has 2 kinds of notifications, one that appears in the drop down notifications menu, and the other that doesn't, yet you can see a red circle (counter) that appears on Facebook icon to indicate that it has an inner notification.

Comment: Once you open Facebook application and preview its Notification section, this red circle (counter) disappears.

Comment: In my opinion the red circle (counter, badge) is not available to check for other applications. I mean you can't check Facebook badge counter from your app. You can do that between your own apps with ContentProviders to read badge counter data from other app.

Comment: @DennyDog Thank you, but how different launchers shows that badge / counter?

Comment: @Jack I dont know, but.. It's Facebook - they can support every launcher :) Check this out: https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Answer (score 1):

The name of the circle/number is Badge. From [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges):

> notification badges (also known as notification dots) appear on a
>   launcher icon when the associated app has an active notification

Therefore it seems like the badges will turn up in the `NotificationListenerService` (as described in your provided link) since they are based on "real" notifications.